# How do I configure my docker container to run in the browser?

Tags: docker, meteor, docker-compose, containers

How do I correctly configure and build my docker container/image to run on the web browser?

I have a meteor webapp, and using one of the existing base images: **jshimko/meteor-launchpad**, that comes recommended by the official Meteor Guide on [Depolyment & Monitoring](https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html), tutorial found at [meteor-launchpad-github](https://github.com/jshimko/meteor-launchpad). I have been able to build an image based on my **web app**, but its never assigned a **port**, therefore I am unable to run it in the browser.

Added the `Dockerfile` to the root of my web app, and added the following contents

```
FROM debian:jessie
```

To build the image, I then run the below in the terminal

```
docker build -t sirbt/myapp .
```

Which yeilded:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.331MB
Step 1/1 : FROM debian:jessie
 ---> b6e9658de383
Successfully built b6e9658de383
Successfully tagged sirbt/myapp:latest
```

I then commence to saving the following contents in the `.dockerignore` file that I also save in the app directory root

```
.git
.meteor/local
node_modules
```

and then run the code below to run **myapp** in the container

```
docker run -d \
  -e ROOT_URL=http://example.com \
  -e MONGO_URL=mongodb://url \
  -e MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://oplog_url \
  -e MAIL_URL=smtp://mail_url.com \
  -p 70:3000 \
  sirbt/myapp
```

the code then yeilds:

```
4e616999e521014fcb19d33869b45c79d93d6774d2d02e2f413343b72294f88b
```

I follow this by command:

```
docker ps
```

Which yeild:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS   NAMES
```

However

`docker ps -a` yeilds:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS PORTS                                      NAMES
4e616999e521        sirbt/myapp         "bash"                   3 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                           compassionate_greider
```

As you can tell, no **port** is assigned to the container to enable me to run it on the browser. The tutorial suggest that at this point I should be able to run it on the localhost on port 80 **(in my case port 70)**. What am I missing here? How can I configure my docker container so that is assigned a port, enabling me to run it in the browser?

Find below the contents of my `docker-compose.yml`

```
# docker-compose.yml

app:
  image: yourname/app
  ports:
    - "70:3000"
  links:
    - mongo
  environment:
    - ROOT_URL=http://example.com
    - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/meteor

mongo:
  image: mongo:latest
  command: mongod --storageEngine=wiredTiger
```

**Update to reflect why I am not using** `FROM jshimko/meteor-launchpad:latest` in my dockerfile

When I update my Dockerfile with `FROM jshimko/meteor-launchpad:latest` as suggested in the tutorial. I get the following error message:

```
`Get:6 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
Fetched 10.1 MB in 8s (1154 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
The command '/bin/sh -c cd $APP_SOURCE_DIR &&   $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/install-deps.sh &&   $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/install-node.sh &&   $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/install-phantom.sh &&   $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/install-graphicsmagick.sh &&   $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/install-mongo.sh &&   $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/install-meteor.sh &&   $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/build-meteor.sh &&   $BUILD_SCRIPTS_DIR/post-build-cleanup.sh' returned a non-zero code: 100`
```

Comment: your container are exited. Check the logs using ** docker logs -f <container-id>** and update the log in question. You might be missing something.

Comment: @Akshaybarahate Thanks for the prompt response sadly the `docker logs -f 9a613c49cd46` command doesn't yield anything. Kindly revert

Comment: Is that your entire Dockerfile, that single line?  Do you `COPY` your application in or set a default `CMD`?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, unfortunately, that's it! I am a newbie to Docker images, and it seemed like the tutorial was complete. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to read the meteor-launchpad tutorial closely, as it looks like you've missed a couple points.

I notice you said your Dockerfile is:

```
FROM debian:jessie
```

That's your main problem.  It should be:

```
FROM jshimko/meteor-launchpad:latest
```

(or `FROM jshimko/meteor-launchpad:some-specific-version`).

By changing the `FROM`, you've made the rest of the tutorial irrelevant.  You're now just building and running a basic Debian container that doesn't do anything.

Unfortunately, it looks like the `meteor-launchpad` image is broken.  It hasn't been updated in about 2 years, and it's built on an old version of Debian whose sources have been archived - that is the cause of your build error (see https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/issues/66).

If you really want to use `meteor-launchpad`, I'd recommend cloning its repo and building the image yourself.

```
git clone https://github.com/jshimko/meteor-launchpad.git
cd meteor-launchpad
docker build -t jshimko/meteor-launchpad:latest .
```

After doing that, you can probably follow the tutorial; however, you might need to change `FROM debian:jessie` in the meteor-launchpad Dockerfile to use a more recent Debian version.  This is not a production-worthy solution, but I'm recommending it since it sounds like you're just trying to get a learning project up and running.

I'd recommend reading up on Docker concepts, since the meteor-launchpad docs seem to assume you're pretty familiar with them.  You could start with [Docker's own tutorial docs](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/).

---

Also, your `docker-compose.yml` file is not being used.  Docker Compose is an *alternative* to issuing `docker run` commands directly; to use it, run the command `docker-compose up [-d]` from the directory where the YML file is located.  Using just the `docker run` command you posted will start a container from the image you built, but it won't start a mongo container.  You would have to start that separately.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I have updated the original question by explaining why I changed the FROM parameters